jest jsdom - dom.window.document.getElementById(X) succeeds but document.getElementById(X) fails
This one is a real head scratcher, neither Google nor ChatGPT could solve it.
This is a simple and straightforward jest test using jsdom, I've seen dozens like it in blogs and Github.

The 1000ms sleep is just to prove its not a timing issue.
document.documentElement.outerHTML shows the HTML content.
document is a valid Document object.
document.getElementById is a valid function
document.getElementById('loginEmailForm') returns null for an unknown reason
any number of calls to dom.window.document.getElementById('loginEmailForm') before or after  document.getElementById('loginEmailForm') return HTMLElement{}
window.document.getElementById('loginEmailForm') and document.getElementById('loginEmailForm') always return null.

I have no explanation for the behavior above, I'm hoping someone has seen it before, or at least can reproduce it.
node is v22.3.0
jest is v29.7.0
jsdom is v24.1.0
const { JSDOM } = require('jsdom');

beforeEach(() => {
  jest.resetModules();

  const dom = new JSDOM(`
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title>test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
      <form id="loginEmailForm">
        <input type="email" id="email">
        <span id="emailError"></span>
        <button type="submit">Submit</button>
      </form>
    </body>
    </html>
  `, { runScripts: "dangerously" });

  global.dom = dom;
  global.window = dom.window;
  global.document = dom.window.document;

  require('../src/login-email.js');
});

describe('Login Email Form', () => {
  test('form and input elements exist', async () => {
    await new Promise(resolve => setTimeout(resolve, 1000));
    console.log("document:", document.documentElement.outerHTML);
    console.log(document);
    console.log(document.getElementById);
    console.log(document.getElementById('loginEmailForm'));
    console.log(dom.window.document.getElementById('loginEmailForm'));

    expect(dom.window.document.getElementById('loginEmailForm')).not.toBeNull();
    expect(dom.window.document.getElementById('email')).not.toBeNull();
    expect(dom.window.document.getElementById('emailError')).not.toBeNull();
  });
});


Sorry, what's the issue exactly? This all works for me as expected. I'm not seeing any nulls.

@ggorlen Well that is not good because I see nulls every time - this might be a dependency hell issue. What versions of node, jest, and jsdom are you usng?

jsdom ^24.0.0, node 20.11.1, npm 10.2.4, Ubuntu 22.04.4 LTS. I didn't use Jest, so maybe that's worth checking on your end (it doesn't seem like it should matter, though, unless there's a Jest setup file in the mix). If Jest does seem to matter, let me know and I'll try it.

Yes, this was some sort of nodejs dependency hell issue, I started with a clean docker image with only jest and jsdom installed and tests run as expected.
